# SQL - check if column exists within stored procedure (table is variable)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This doesn't seem to have been answered anywhere (although very similar cases have been answered)...

I have an issue where I am trying to update a column's value in a table within a stored procedure. However, I pass more than one table to this stored procedure and some tables have a certain column and others don't. Thus I need to check if the column exists before I run this update. Now, because it's in a stored procedure, SQL seems to be parsing the entire chunk of code up front and complains that this column doesn't exist.

Code:

```
IF COL_LENGTH(''DBName' + @date+ '..' + @TableName + @date+''', ''ColumnName' + @specifictocolumn + 'restofcolumnname'') IS NOT NULL
    update  DBName' + @date+ '..' + @TableName + @date+ ' set ColumnName' + @specifictocolumn + 'restofcolumnname = 0
```

Alternatively

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N''ColumnName' + @specifictocolumn + 'restofcolumnname '' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N''DBName' + @date+ '..' + @TableName + @date+'''))
    update  DBName' + @date+ '..' + @TableName + @date+ ' set ColumnName' + @specifictocolumn + 'restofcolumnname = 0
```

Both of these give the error (column name removed for IP purposes):

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Invalid column name 'ColumnName'.

There is a question on stack overflow called "Disable TSQL script check" that I looked at, but they suggest that you call the check of the column outside of the dynamic sql and then only execute if it passes the check. This won't work for me because part of the if-statement has variables in it that need to be in dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still split the dynamic SQL in 2 parts:

1. check if the column exists
2. do the actual update when 1. returns true

you'll probably want to use `sp_executesql` for this and an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Something along the lines of this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @result int

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT @col_length = COL_LENGTH(''DBName' + @date + '..' + @TableName + @date + ''', ''ColumnName' + @specifictocolumn + 'restofcolumnname'')'

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @sql,
                   @params = N'@col_length int OUTPUT',
                   @col_length = @result OUTPUT

IF @result IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        EXEC ('update  DBName' + @date+ '..' + @TableName + @date+ ' set ColumnName' + @specifictocolumn + 'restofcolumnname = 0') 
    END
```

Or you could go 'dynamic inside dynamic', but will become a mess very quickly.

Comment: Ah, you are fantastic! Thank you so much, this works exactly how I wanted.